# Java - how to call a method of corresponding class based on string using enum/factory pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums, factory-pattern

Yes, I read many examples in web, but I didn't find a way how to call a method based on string value. May be I am not searching in right way... I wrote all code, but don't know how to call the method. 
fyi: I don't want to use `if else` or `switch case`

Here is what I want:
I get the card reader type as String from database. I have to call the corresponding class' method.

My code:

**LoginPanel.java**

```
public class LoginPanel {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String readerType = "Omnikey5427-CK"; // I get this ("Omnikey5427-CK" or "Omnikey5427-G2") from a database as String 

        // I WANT TO CALL getCardNumber() method of respective class


    }
}
```

**ISmartCardReader.java**

```
public interface ISmartCardReader {

    public Integer getCardNumber();

}
```

**Omnikey5427G2.java**

```
public class Omnikey5427G2 implements ISmartCardReader {

    public Omnikey5427G2() {
        System.out.println("G222222222222222...");
    }

    public Integer getCardNumber() {
        return 222;
    }
}
```

**Omnikey5427CK.java**

```
public class Omnikey5427CK implements ISmartCardReader {

    public Omnikey5427CK() {
        System.out.println("CKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK...");
    }

    public Integer getCardNumber() {
        return 111;
    }
}
```

**SmacrtCardEnumFactory.java**

```
public enum SmacrtCardEnumFactory {

    OMNIKEY5427CK("Omnikey5427-CK") {
        public ISmartCardReader geInstance() {
            return new Omnikey5427CK();
        }
    },
    OMNIKEY5427G2("Omnikey5427-G2") {
        public ISmartCardReader geInstance() {
            return new Omnikey5427G2();
        }
    };

    private String cardReaderName;

    private SmacrtCardEnumFactory(String cardReaderName) {
        this.cardReaderName = cardReaderName;
    }

    public String cardReaderName() {
        return cardReaderName;
    }

}
```

Comment: if ( "test".equals(myString)) return test(); else if ( "notTest".equals(myString)) return notTest(); something like that probably

Comment: @Stultuske - I don't want to use `if else` or `switch case`

Comment: You need to implement a parsing system  to convert the strings into their enum counterparts. You could take your db string, take out the hyphen, make it all uppercase, and call `SmartCardEnumFactory.valueOf(modifiedDbString)` to obtain the instance you need, which you can then call the proper method needed.

Comment: @VinceEmigh - I did think about that, but it is a sample string, it could be different. As per API, they can add a new card and they will add a new item in enum (i.e. SmacrtCardEnumFactory)

Comment: If scaling is a worry, you need to figure out the standard so you can write a proper parser: figure out the naming convention so you can write a parser that scales. If there is no convention/standard, then there's no way to determine what corner cases may pop up, causing you to update your code as new versions are released.

Comment: Maybe you can add ann annotation to every class that contains its own string-rpresentation and which can then be read by the factory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use valueOf() function of enum provided your enum sonstant names match strings used to lookup (you may use cardName.toUpper()).   You may also create objects for all the card types and store them in a hash map and  then lookup them.  You can also write some fatory method, but this will be if-then-else or switch  inside

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the factory's `values()` and get the one that matches the string:

```java
public enum SmacrtCardEnumFactory {
    // current code omitted for brevity

    public static getSmartCardReader(String name) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                     .filter(r -> r.cardReaderName().equals(name))
                     .map(SmacrtCardEnumFactory::getInstance();
                     .orElse(null);
    }
}
```